# Getting answer of 2 raised higher than 63 without using additional libraries

Tags: c++, math

I was wondering what is the best method to get the answer to something like 2^65 without using additional libraries which would accommodate for more space than standard 64 bit data types. I thought about using chars but that seems like would take a lot of computing time.

Comment: Why don't you want to use an external library?

Comment: `__int128`, built-in type of quite a few compilers

Comment: You probably would need to build your own data type. You'd need a counter for how many sets of int64 MAX (or whatever datatype you're using) your number has. It's similar to doing a conversion from base 10 to base 32 (or whatever), only you're converting to base int64 MAX.

Comment: Not a perfect answer, but `double` can represent powers of two up to 1023.

Comment: Of course, you could use floating-point... But that is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: well I lose a lot of precision that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have mapped numbers up to a few billion by letting each bit in an int represent a number. This would be an array of ints so the 5th bit of the 3rd int in the array would be (((2 * 32) - 1) + 5) 68 and the 2nd bit of the 2nd int would be (((1 * 32) - 1) + 2) 33 etc. etc. With this way all you need to do to map higher numbers is increase your array size. The overall space needed will be 32 times less than it would need to be otherwise and you can have all the numbers up to the limit mapped. But, you can only have 1 of each number with this method.